# Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, roman-numerals

Following minimal document:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand*\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{chapter}{6} % Problem starts at chapter 7
\chapter{Seven}
\chapter{Eight}
\section{Eight-one}
\section{Eight-two}
\end{document}
```

yields this output (cut to size for your convenience):

[image: screenshot]

Clearly, the chapter (and section) headings hang into the chapter (section) numbers. For the previous chapter numbers, this isn’t a problem since all chapter titles are aligned to the same column and the numbers I–VI are sufficiently narrow.

(The same happens regardless of document type, I’m actually using `scrreprt` with the same result.)

How can I prevent this?

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20210506201535/http://projekte.dante.de/DanteFAQ/Verzeichnisse#3 or look for packages like `titletoc`.

Comment: For which class do you need a fix? A solution for `scrreprt` may be easier. A solution for `report` doesn't necessarily have to be the best for scrreprt.

Comment: @Stefan: someone once told me to always use standard classes for MWEs. I’m actually using `screprt`. I didn’t find a solution in the KOMA documentation, though.

Comment: if the problem is not depending on class features, a standard class MWE is fine. Here I just prefer a tiny class adjustment over a general package which is 1110 lines long and replaces many class macros, besides the TOC also for lists of tables and contents.

Comment: For a [`memoir`](//ctan.org/pkg/memoir) solution, see [`memoir`: Roman chapters in ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/575196/5764)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could also use the `tocstyle` package, part of KOMA-script:

```
\documentclass[pagesize]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[tocindentauto]{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{KOMAlike} %the previous line resets it
\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{chapter}{6} % Problem starts at chapter 7
\chapter{Seven}
\chapter{Eight}
\section{Eight-one}
\section{Eight-two}
\end{document}
```

(compile twice)

Comment: Of all the solutions here, this one probably plays nicest with KOMA. Oddly enough, it also resets the TOC style to “normal” so that the style explicitly needs to be reset to KOMA-like.

Comment: I got directed here from question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/609861/chapter-section-number-sticking-to-title-in-table-of-content , but when I include \usepackage[tocindentauto]{tocstyle} and the other things, to my document, the document is not getting any change and log gets blanks (so I'm not even sure if it comipled at all).

Comment: Package `tocstyle` never reached version 1, always warned, that it is only an alpha version made for testing only, and now is deprecated and has been removed not only from KOMA-Script but also from TeX Live and MiKTeX. Therefore, in my opinion, this answer is of historical interest at best.

Answer (score 13):

For the record, I ended up using the `tocloft` package, as follows

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
```

(Option `titles` since all I want from the package is manipulate the space of the table of content lines; the title should still be rendered using the standard LaTeX method).

```
\renewcommand*\cftchapnumwidth{2em}
\renewcommand*\cftsecnumwidth{3em}
```

That said, it’s perhaps more appropriate to change the display of the contents lines so that only the section number is displayed for sections, not the whole “chapter.section” number.

Comment: Wow! This is such a simple solution for a problem that tends to make your ToC really ugly when using roman numerals. Thank you @konrad-rudolph for adding it here! It saved a ton of hassle for me! Cheers!

Answer (score 12):

Since KOMA-Script version 3.20 there are options to change the style of the TOC or list entries. You can use

```
\RedeclareSectionCommands[tocdynnumwidth]{chapter,section}
```

to get

[image]

or

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocnumwidth=2.3em]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocindent=2.3em,tocnumwidth=3.2em]{section}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}[2016/05/10]% needs version 3.20 or newer
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocnumwidth=2.3em]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocindent=2.3em,tocnumwidth=3.2em]{section}
\renewcommand*\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{chapter}{6} % Problem starts at chapter 7
\chapter{Seven}
\chapter{Eight}
\section{Eight-one}
\section{Eight-two}
\end{document}
```

---

It is also possible to use package `tocbasic` (which is part of the KOMA-Script bundle) with a standard class. Then you can use

```
\usepackage{tocbasic}[2017/01/03]% needs version 3.22
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[dynnumwidth]{tocline}{chapter}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[dynnumwidth]{tocline}{section}
```

[image]

or

```
\usepackage{tocbasic}[2016/05/10]
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=2.6em]{tocline}{chapter}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent=2.6em,numwidth=3.2em]{tocline}{section}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\renewcommand*\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}

\usepackage{tocbasic}[2016/05/10]
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=2.6em]{tocline}{chapter}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent=2.6em,numwidth=3.2em]{tocline}{section}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\setcounter{chapter}{6} % Problem starts at chapter 7
\chapter{Seven}
\chapter{Eight}
\section{Eight-one}
\section{Eight-two}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

tocloft works fine with standard classes. If I use KOMA classes, such as the mentioned `scrreprt`, I don't like tocloft to redefine class macros. For example, features such as koma fonts and the auto end dot are would be lost.

I would make a small modification myself, so I know that few is changed:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\raggedchapterentry}{\setlength\@tempdima{2.3em}}
\renewcommand*\l@section{\bprot@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3.2em}}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: I’m extremely wary of such low-level modifications since they (1) require an intimate knowledge of the classes that surpasses the documented features by far, and (2) is extremely fragile, i.e. not future-proof. Any minor change in the `scrreprt` class may break this code. This is also the reason why I usually abhor the concept of these super classes like KOMA and memoir (and, indeed, ConTeXt). A modular approach (as implemented by packages) is technically much more sound. Put differently, this problem showcases everything that’s wrong with the “architecture” of TeX. :-(

Comment: (That said, I’m grateful for the answer and I’ll probably use it.)

Comment: Please do not redefine `\l@section` this way with newer versions of KOMA-Script.

Answer (score 5):

I'll provide an example of the use of `titletoc` for this problem. It requires loading the `eqparbox` package to have an automatic alignment of chapter titles, section titles, &c.:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry} 
% Font Style
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{\vspace{.25\baselineskip}}
{\eqparbox{ch}{\bfseries\thecontentslabel}\enspace}{}
{\hspace{.5em}\hfill\contentspage}

\titlecontents{section}[0em]{\vspace{.25\baselineskip}}
{\hskip\eqboxwidth{ch}{}\enspace\eqparbox{sec}{\thecontentslabel}\enspace}{}
{\hspace{.5em}\titlerule*[10pt]{$\cdot$}\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand*\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{chapter}{6} % Problem starts at chapter 7
\chapter{Seven}
\chapter{Eight}
\section{Eight-one} \thesection\setcounter{section}{99}
\section{Eight-hundred}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem today and I found that there is an easy solution for me without changing the font of the section title (like what KOMAlike tocstyle does).

```
\documentclass[pagesize]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
....
\end{document}
```

There are other predefined tocstyle you can choose if you would like to explore more options(See [tocstyle manual](http://www.bakoma-tex.com/doc/latex/koma-script/tocstyle.pdf)). Hope this would be helpful for future readers.

Comment: Package `tocstyle` was always only an experimental package, that has always warned, to not use it for something else than experiments. Meanwhile it is deprecated and no longer part of TeX distributions.