# Extra space for numbered titles in table of contents

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, koma-script, tocloft

### Background

A manual with chapters, sections, subsections, and sub-subsections. Using KOMA Script v2.

### Problem

The spacing between the heading title and its number is too close to the number in some cases:

[image]

After reading the `tocloft` package, I do not see how to adjust the spacing between the heading title and the number.

### Question

How do you increase the space before the section title a consistent amount?

### Ideas

Tried including the following package:

```
\usepackage[tocindentauto]{tocstyle}
```

Tried setting linewidth:

```
\setlength{\linewidth}{15em}
```

Tried setting the dottedtocline:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\l@section}{\@dottedtocline{1}{4.5em}{5.3em}}
\makeatother
```

The last attempt looks promising, but it is tricky to adjust the margins correctly.

### References

- [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7415/roman-numerals-become-too-wide-in-table-of-contents)
- http://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-users@lists.lyx.org/msg10853.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Current KOMA-Script release provides options `tocindent` and `tocnumwidth` for `\RedeclareSectionCommand` that allows to change the indent and the space reserved for the entry number without breaking any feature of the KOMA-Script classes.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocnumwidth=2.6em]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocindent=4.1em,tocnumwidth=3.5em]{subsection}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
% Only some dummy test code:
\clearpage
\setcounter{chapter}{15}
\setcounter{section}{9}
\section{Classes}
\subsection{Abstract}
\subsection{Concrete}
\subsection{Exception}
\section{Automation}
\section{Summary}
\end{document}
```

e.g., would result in:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

For me, tocstyle produces correct horizontal spacing with both standard and KOMA-script classes. Try to compile my example with three or even four LaTeX runs -- maybe the makefile you use doesn't recognize that tocstyle needs yet another LaTeX run to calculate the ToC spacing.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{tocstyle}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{chapter}{100}
\chapter{bla}
\setcounter{section}{200}
\section{blubb}
\setcounter{subsection}{300}
\subsection{foo}
\setcounter{subsubsection}{400}
\subsubsection{bar}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not sure if this is an exact reproduction of the problem, though. The preamble for this manual is 1000 lines long. Inside I have set different fonts. Also, I'm using tocloft, not tocstyle (if that matters).

Comment: @Dave: Yes, it matters. My suggestion boils down to use tocstyle *instead* of tocloft.

Comment: @Dave: One of the features of tocstyle is automatic calculation of ToC spacing instead of using fixed pre-set values.

Comment: Substituting *tocstyle* for *tocloft* results in a lot of "Undefined control sequence" errors that I have neither the time nor inclination to resolve. One day, perhaps, latex will generate errors that are a bit more meaningful to the lay person. I do appreciate you taking the time to suggest an alternative, though!

Comment: `tocstyle` is deprecated and not longer provides by the TeX distriutions.

Answer (score 1):

When using `tocloft` is a requirement, the `\cftsetindents` command solves the given issue, for example:

```
\cftsetindents{section}{0em}{2.5em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{1em}{3.5em}
```

With this solution, different indents and numwidths can be set for each level. This command can also be used for figures; for more see the `tocloft` package manual.

Comment: Is this compatible with [KOMA-script](//ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes as requested in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the preamble:

```
\usepackage[tocindentauto]{tocstyle}
```

followed by

```
\usetocstyle{standard}
```

or by

```
\usetocstyle{KOMAlike}
```

Comment: `tocstyle` is a never supported alpha package. The KOMA-Script author recommends to not longer use it and declared to never release a version 1. You should use package `tocbasic` (see the accepted answer) instead.