# How to replace fixed indentation of ToC entry names with fixed space between number and name?

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, tocloft

How to make indents as in the second image?

This is what it looks like now:

[image]

This is what it should look like:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt, english]{extreport}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=25mm, right=10mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}

\linespread{1.3} 
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ftm} 
\frenchspacing

\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalsize  } 
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\normalfont} 

\renewcommand{\cftbeforechapskip}{0em} 
\renewcommand{\cftparskip}{-1mm} 
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1} 
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\cftsetindents{chapter}{0pt}{10pt} 
\cftsetindents{section}{0pt}{30pt}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{0pt}{40pt}
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{0pt}{50pt}



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty} 
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}

\chapter{test}
\section{test} 
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test} 
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test} 
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related or duplicated: [How to modify the indentation before sectioning titles in the table of contents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33841/how-to-modify-the-indentation-before-sectioning-titles-in-the-table-of-contents/33842#33842)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to learn more about how to get the most out of this site.

Comment: also related: [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415/579) and [Extra space for numbered titles in table of contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13690/579)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel The OP seems to want to replace fixed indentation of section names with a fixed space between section number and name. Taking a quick look at the `tocloft` manual, it's not obvious how to achieve this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The package `tocloft` supports this indirect. However this modification allows all settings by `tocloft`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{%
  \setbox0\hbox{#1\quad}%
  \hb@xt@\wd0{\@cftbsnum #1\@cftasnum\hfil}\@cftasnumb}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{foo}
\section{bar}
\section{bar}
\setcounter{section}{170}
\section{bar}
\section{bar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

While I can't offer a `tocloft` solution, the desired layout can be achieved by using the `tocstyle` package (part of [`KOMA-Script`](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)) and its `tocfullflat` option.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[tocfullflat]{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{allwithdot}
\settocstylefeature[0]{entryhook}{\normalfont}
\settocstylefeature[0]{entryvskip}{0pt}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@dotsep}{1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{test}
\section{test} 
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test} 
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test} 
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]