# List of figures indentation

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation

I am writing my thesis and I am experiencing a problem with the space between numbering and the image name. You can see the problem in the picture I include in this question. It starts from 3.10.

How can I fix that?

[image]

Comment: Turns out that I have to rest a bit cause I cant write something correctly. It is about list of figures and not toc. I am sorry.

Comment: Look for `\l@figure` in Marco Daniel's answer to the linked question.

Comment: The method is equal and described too

Comment: also related: [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415/579) and [Extra space for numbered titles in table of contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13691/579)