# margins or line breaks in koma-script table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, margins, koma-script

Entries in my KOMA-script TOC spread too close from the page numbers:
[image]

One solution is to use a *short title* and insert in it a line-break, but this is not an acceptable solution.

I am trying to modify the *[tocrmarge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13690/extra-space-for-numbered-titles-in-table-of-contents)*. Here are my attempts, but all compile with errors:

```
\makeatletter
% one and one only of the following
\renewcommand*{\settocfeature}{tocrmarge}{10em}
\renewcommand*\l@tocrmarge}{10em}
\renewcommand*{\settocfeature}{\setlength{\@tocrmarge}{10em}}
\makeatother
```

My understanding of LaTeX is not good enough. I need help to write correctly the command please.

EDIT: add a MWE (not so minimal in the preambul)

```
\documentclass[english,enlargefirstpage, full]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[paperwidth=148mm,paperheight=210mm]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=3cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
\usepackage{ulem}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{lettrine}{\usepackage{lettrine}}{}
\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
\usepackage[english,frenchle]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\renewcommand{\sectfont}{\normalfont\bfseries} %\slshape} %\rmfamily}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@chapter{\bprot@dottedtocline{1}{1.8em}{3.2em}}
\renewcommand*\l@section{\bprot@dottedtocline{1}{1.8em}{3.2em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\bprot@dottedtocline{3}{1.8em}{3.2em}}
\makeatother

\frenchspacing
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\hyphenpenalty=3500
\doublehyphendemerits=9000
\finalhyphendemerits=6000

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[babel=true,kerning=french,protrusion=true,expansion=auto,spacing,tracking]{microtype}
\pretolerance=1500
\tolerance=2000
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{2em}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\labelitemi{\Pisymbol{psy}{42}}
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\title{my book title}
\subtitle{my book subtitle}
\author{\textbf{myself}}
\maketitle
\frontmatter
\chapter{Before}
blublu
\tableofcontents{}
\newpage{}\mainmatter
\part{PROLOG}
\chapter{\emph{chapter 1}}
blabla
\chapter{\emph{chapter 2 title is very long and should look uggly}}
bloblo
\end{document}
```

And its result (not as uggly as in my real document):

[image]

EDIT: Here is the successful build [log](http://pastebin.com/FHyeGjY5) (in a pastbin, since otherwise I exceed the *Stack Exchange* 30,000 characters body limit.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I would rather say, that for some reason your entry name is too long. Did you consider a short entry for the toc such as `\section[shorttitle]{long title}`?

Comment: No, the title cannot be shorten.

Comment: Your example does not compile

Comment: I have added the successful build log in the OP. I will try to modify the MWE to be really minimal, hoping it will help. Possibly you don't have the french stuff in your setup ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this with one of the two following solutions:

Either:

```
\renewcommand*\@pnumwidth{2em}
```

Or:

```
\renewcommand*\@tocrmarg{3em}
```

Answer (score 1):

add into the preamble:

```
[...]
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\bprot@dottedtocline{3}{1.8em}{3.2em}}
\renewcommand*\@pnumwidth{3em}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  the width of the page number
\makeatother
[...]
```

[image]

Your preamble looks a bit weird ...

Comment: Thanks Herbert ! For the weirdness of the preambul, I do agree with you. I am considering using texmaker instead of LyX, what will give me full control on things.