# Table numbers overwrite table captions in list of tables with double-digit tables

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation

I am having a problem where the table numbers overrun into the table captions in my list of tables for tables with longer numbers.  I am using the attached nuthesis.cls file (based on amsbook.cls).  I have tried using the tocloft package with no success.  The suggestion in:

[List of figures and list of tables overlaps figure/table indices with proceeding text when double figures are used](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22983/list-of-figures-and-list-of-tables-overlaps-figure-table-indices-with-proceeding)

also does not work.

Below is a MWE - thanks in advance for the help!  I would also like to eliminate the extra floating period after Appendix in the table of contents.  Any suggestions?

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{nuthesis}  % The nuthesis class is based on
                    % amsbook.cls.
    \usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,epsfig,float,enumerate,import,rotating,here,array,comment,subfigure}
    %\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}

    %\makeatletter
    %\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3em}}% 3em instead of 2.3em
    %\let\l@table\l@figure
    %\makeatother



    \author{AUTHOR NAME}
    \title{Essays}
    \degree{DOCTOR OF PHILOSOPHY}  % Default: DOCTOR OF PHILOSOPHY
    \field{FIELD}                  % Default: Mathematics
    \graduationmonth{August}    
    \graduationyear{2012}       
    \begin{document}
    \frontmatter        % Preliminary pages start here.
    \maketitle      % Produces the title page.
    \copyrightpage      % Creates the copyright page.
    \abstract       % Abstract.
        What you did
    \acknowledgements   % Acknowledgements (optional).
        Thanks.
    \tableofcontents
    \listoftables       % List of Tables and List of Figures will be placed
    \listoffigures      % here, if applicable (optional).

    \mainmatter             % Actual text starts here.

    \chapter{Chapter 1} 
    \section{Introduction}

    I would love my table names to not be written over by numbers.
    \setcounter{table}{9}
    \begin{table}[htbp]\centering \footnotesize
      \caption[Summary Statistics]{Summary Statistics \label{sumstats_bondanalysis}}
        \begin{tabular}{cc}\hline\hline
           Name &    N \\
           XYZ & 5 \\\hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \appendix 
    \chapter{Data Appendix}
    \end{document}
```

The nuthesis.cls code is:

```
    %%% This is nuthesis.cls
    %%% for writing doctoral dissertations at the
    %%% Mathematics Department of Northwestern University; and
    %%% Electrical Engineering and Computer Science, Northwestern University
    %%%
    %%% Author: Miguel A. Lerma (mlerma@math.northwestern.edu)
    %%% Date:5/4/2005
    %%% Edited by: Debjit Sinha (debjitsinha@yahoo.com)
    %%% for NU Electronic dissertation requirements.
    %%% Date:4/15/2006
    %%%
    %%% ====================================================================
    %% \CharacterTable
    %%  {Upper-case    \A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H\I\J\K\L\M\N\O\P\Q\R\S\T\U\V\W\X\Y\Z
    %%   Lower-case    \a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\j\k\l\m\n\o\p\q\r\s\t\u\v\w\x\y\z
    %%   Digits        \0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9
    %%   Exclamation   \!     Double quote  \"     Hash (number) \#
    %%   Dollar        \$     Percent       \%     Ampersand     \&
    %%   Acute accent  \'     Left paren    \(     Right paren   \)
    %%   Asterisk      \*     Plus          \+     Comma         \,
    %%   Minus         \-     Point         \.     Solidus       \/
    %%   Colon         \:     Semicolon     \;     Less than     \<
    %%   Equals        \=     Greater than  \>     Question mark \?
    %%   Commercial at \@     Left bracket  \[     Backslash     \\
    %%   Right bracket \]     Circumflex    \^     Underscore    \_
    %%   Grave accent  \`     Left brace    \{     Vertical bar  \|
    %%   Right brace   \}     Tilde         \~}
    \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}% LaTeX 2.09 can't be used (nor non-LaTeX)
    [1994/12/01]% LaTeX date must December 1994 or later
    \ProvidesClass{nuthesis}[2005/05/04 v1.6a by Miguel A. Lerma]
    \PassOptionsToClass{oneside}{amsbook}
    \DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{amsbook}}
    \ProcessOptions\relax
    \LoadClass{amsbook}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    %\def\singlespace{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}}
    %\def\singlehalfspace{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}}
    %\def\doublespace{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.8}}

    %\RequirePackage{doublespace}       % MAL - 5/8/2001
    %\def\onehalfspace{\spacing{1.4}}   % MAL - 5/8/2001
    %\def\doublespace{\spacing{1.8}}    % MAL - 5/8/2001

    \RequirePackage{setspace}                        % MAL - 4/19/2003
    \renewcommand{\onehalfspacing}{\setstretch{1.4}} % MAL - 4/19/2003
    \renewcommand{\doublespacing}{\setstretch{1.8}}  % MAL - 4/19/2003

    % Page numbering should be at normal size
    % (amsbook.cls yields scriptsize) - MAL 6/17/2003
    \def\ps@plain{\ps@empty
      \def\@oddfoot{\normalfont\normalsize \hfil\thepage\hfil}%
      \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}

    % Another place where amsbook.cls yields scriptsize
    % (amsbook.cls yields scriptsize) - MAL 7/15/2003
    \def\ps@headings{\ps@empty
      \def\@evenhead{%
        \setTrue{runhead}%
        \normalfont\normalsize        % changed from scriptsize - MAL 7/15/2003
        \rlap{\thepage}\hfil \leftmark{}{}\hfil}%
      \def\@oddhead{%
        \setTrue{runhead}%
        \normalfont\normalsize \hfil  % changed from scriptsize - MAL 7/15/2003
        \rightmark{}{}\hfil \llap{\thepage}}%
      \let\@mkboth\markboth
      \def\partmark{\@secmark\markboth\partrunhead\partname}%
      \def\chaptermark{%
        \@secmark\markboth\chapterrunhead{}}%
      \def\sectionmark{%
        \@secmark\markright\sectionrunhead\sectionname}%
    }

    \def\contentsname{Table of Contents}

    \def\chapter{%
      \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
      \thispagestyle{myheadings}\global\@topnum\z@
      \@afterindenttrue \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}

    \setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in}
    \setlength{\headheight}{0.2in}
    \setlength{\headsep}{0.5in}

    \setlength{\textheight}{8.2in}
    \setlength{\footskip}{0.0in}

    \setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
    \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
    \setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0in}

    \renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\@arabic\c@section}
    \renewcommand\thefigure {\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}
    \renewcommand\thetable {\thechapter.\arabic{table}}


    \newcommand{\numwidth}{10em}

    %% SECTION heading spacing and font
    %%
    % arguments are: #1 - sectiontype name
    % (for \@sect)   #2 - section level
    %                #3 - indent
    %                #4 - top separation
    %                #5 - tempskipa, bottom separation
    %                #6 - font control
    % if tempskipa <= 0 the heading is a run-in heading

    \def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}%
      \z@{.7\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
      {\normalfont\bfseries\centering}}
    \def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}%
      \z@{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
      {\normalfont\bfseries}}
    \def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}%
      \z@\z@{-.5em}%
      {\normalfont\bfseries}}

    \def\th@plain{%
      \thm@headfont{\bfseries}
      \let\thmhead\thmhead@plain \let\swappedhead\swappedhead@plain
      \thm@preskip.5\baselineskip\@plus.2\baselineskip
                                        \@minus.2\baselineskip
      \thm@postskip\thm@preskip
      \itshape
    }
    \def\th@definition{%
      \thm@headfont{\bfseries}%
      \let\thmhead\thmhead@plain \let\swappedhead\swappedhead@plain
      \thm@preskip.5\baselineskip\@plus.2\baselineskip
                                        \@minus.2\baselineskip
      \thm@postskip\thm@preskip
      \upshape
    }
    \def\th@remark{%
      \thm@headfont{\bfseries}%
      \let\thmhead\thmhead@plain \let\swappedhead\swappedhead@plain
      \thm@preskip.5\baselineskip\@plus.2\baselineskip
                                        \@minus.2\baselineskip
      \thm@postskip\thm@preskip
      \upshape
    }


    % This redefinition of the proof environment is obsolete - MAL 5/4/2005
    %\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par \normalfont
    %  \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@ \trivlist \itemindent\z@
    %  \item[\hskip\labelsep\bfseries
    %    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
    %}{%
    %  \qed\endtrivlist
    %}

    % Better just redefine the font for proofname
    % - suggested by Ezra Getzler 5/4/2005
    \renewcommand{\proofname}{\bfseries{Proof}}


    \numberwithin{equation}{chapter}


    \def\@captionheadfont{\normalfont}  % \scshape in amsbook.cls


    \def\@title{Title of dissertation required}

    \def\degree#1{\def\d@gree{#1}}
    \def\d@gree{DOCTOR OF PHILOSOPHY}   % spelling corrected - MAL 3/8/2002
    \def\field#1{\def\fi@ld{#1}}
    \def\fi@ld{Mathematics}
    \def\campus#1{\def\c@mpus{#1}}
    \def\c@mpus{EVANSTON, ILLINOIS}

    \def\graduation@month{\ifcase\month\or
        June\or June\or June\or June\or June\or June\or December\or
        December\or December\or December\or December\or December\fi}
    \def\graduation@year{\number\year}

    \def\graduationmonth#1{\def\graduation@month{#1}}
    \def\graduationyear#1{\def\graduation@year{#1}}

    \def\@date{\graduation@month \graduation@year}



    \def\frontmatter{%
      \cleardoublepage
    %  \pagenumbering{roman}
    %  \pagestyle{plain}
      \pagenumbering{arabic}
      \pagestyle{myheadings}
    }
    \def\mainmatter{%
      \cleardoublepage
    %  \pagenumbering{arabic}
    %  \pagestyle{myheadings}
    }
    \def\backmatter{\cleardoublepage}


    \def\titlepage{%
      \cleardoublepage
      \thispagestyle{empty}\setcounter{page}{1}}
    \def\endtitlepage{\newpage}


    \def\copyrightpage{%
      \cleardoublepage
    \begin{center}
      \ \\
      \vspace{\fill}
    \copyright \ Copyright by \authors{} \graduation@year \\
    All Rights Reserved
    \vspace{\fill}
    \end{center}}
    \def\endcopyrightpage{\newpage}


    \def\maketitle{\par
      \@topnum\z@ % this prevents figures from falling at the top of page 1
    \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
    NORTHWESTERN UNIVERSITY\par
    \vfill
    {\large \@title}\par
    \vfill
    A DISSERTATION\par
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    SUBMITTED TO THE GRADUATE SCHOOL\par
    IN PARTIAL FULFILLMENT OF THE REQUIREMENTS\par
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    for the degree\par
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \d@gree{}\par
    \vfill
    Field of \fi@ld\par
    \vfill
    By\par
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \ifx\@empty\authors
    Author's name required\par
      \else
      \authors\par
      \fi
    \vfill
    \c@mpus\par
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \graduation@month{} \graduation@year{}
    \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}
    }


    \renewcommand{\abstract}{%
    \chapter*{\abstractname}
    \bigskip
    \begin{center}
    \@title{}\par
    \bigskip
    \authors{}\par
    \end{center}
    \bigskip
    }
    \def\abstractname{ABSTRACT} % capitalized - MAL 5/3/2002


    \newcommand{\acknowledgements}{\chapter*{\acknowledgementsname}}
    \def\acknowledgementsname{Acknowledgments}
    \newcommand{\preface}{\chapter*{\prefacename}}
    \def\prefacename{Preface}
    \newcommand{\introduction}{\chapter*{\introductionname}}
    \def\introductionname{Introduction}
    \newcommand{\vita}{\chapter*{\vitaname}}
    \def\vitaname{Vita}

    % Taken from amsbook.cls and modified.
    % The references must use normal size font,
    % and be single spaced with double space
    % between items.
    \renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
      \@xp\chapter\@xp*\@xp{\bibname}%
    %  \normalfont\footnotesize            % commented out (MAL-5/4/2001)
      \labelsep .5em\relax
      \renewcommand\theenumiv{\arabic{enumiv}}\let\p@enumiv\@empty
      \list{\@biblabel{\theenumiv}}{%
        \settowidth\itemsep\@mainsize      % MAL - 5/9/2001
    %    \singlespace                       % MAL - 5/9/2001
        \begin{singlespace}
        \settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
        \leftmargin\labelwidth \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
        \usecounter{enumiv}}%
      \sloppy \clubpenalty\@M \widowpenalty\clubpenalty
      \sfcode`\.=\@m
    }{%
      \def\@noitemerr{\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
    %  \endsinglespace                      % MAL - 5/9/2001
        \end{singlespace}
      \endlist
    }
    \def\bibname{References}


    \def\appendices{\par
      \c@chapter\z@ \c@section\z@
      \let\chaptername\appendixname
      \def\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}}

    \def\appendix{\par
      \c@chapter\z@ \c@section\z@
      \let\chaptername\appendixname
      \def\thechapter{{}}
      \renewcommand\thesection{\@arabic\c@section}}


    \doublespacing


    \endinput
    %%
    %% End of file `nuthesis.cls'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of `nuthesis.cls` that you have is very old. Update to [the current version](http://math.northwestern.edu/comp-help/template/nuthesis.cls) and the problem goes away.