# List of tables and list of figures is behaving differently

Tags: tables, spacing, table-of-contents

I have got a strange issue within my list of tables.
I made these changes to the commands, which are actually from the template I received.

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}-\arabic{figure}}
\makeatletter \@addtoreset{figure}{section} \makeatother

\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{section}-\arabic{table}}
\makeatletter \@addtoreset{table}{section} \makeatother
```

and changed settings at the appendix like the following:

```
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{A.\arabic{subsection}} 
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesubsection-\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesubsection-\arabic{table}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\section*{Appendix}
```

So far it is actually doing what it is supposed to do but there is an ugly inconsistency.

**List of tables**

[image: Result in list of tables]

**List of figures**

[image: Result in list of figures]

I tried to insert a space as `\s \, \hspace` at several locations in the command to somehow solve the problem but have not been successful.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

**EDIT:**

Excerpt of .lot

```
\contentsline {table}{\numberline {A.4-1}{\ignorespaces THIS WHERE THE CAPTION IS \relax }}{86}{table.caption.1487}%
```

Excerpt of .lof

```
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {A.1-1}{\ignorespaces THIS WHERE THE CAPTION IS\relax }}{59}{figure.caption.225}%
```

Comment: The difference seems to be in the indentation and spacing.  Check the definitions of \l@figure, \l@table and \numberline.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. Could you please specify where to find them. Not completely into Latex yet. Did not find them in console, .lot, .lof, .log, .out, .aux. Meanwhile I share the output of .lof and .lot

Comment: Found an answer while googling for the terms you mentioned. Been searching for hours before. This might be a duplicate but would not have found without asking. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved by adding this command to the preamble

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3em}}% 3em instead of 2.3em
\let\l@table\l@figure
\makeatother
```

Found at this questions after the correct search terms where mentioned in the comments.

[List of figures and list of tables overlaps figure/table indices with proceeding text when double figures are used](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22983/list-of-figures-and-list-of-tables-overlaps-figure-table-indices-with-proceeding)