# Separation between label and Title

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

How can I increase the space between the Section number and the Section-Title in the TOC?
I am using the `titletoc`package and my code currently looks like this:

```
 \contentsmargin[25pt]{0pt}

 \titlecontents{chapter}[\tocsep]
   {\addvspace{4pt}\small\bfseries\sffamily}
   {\hspace*{3pt}\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{\tocsep}}
   {}
   {\hfill\thecontentspage}
   []

 \titlecontents{section}[\tocsep]
   {\addvspace{2pt}\small\sffamily}
   {\hspace*{3pt}\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{\tocsep}}
   {}
   {\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\ \thecontentspage}
   []
```

If the number of the section gets high, the number and the text are too close. How can I make it more look like this:

1.23      ~~~~ Title of the Section

than

1.23  Title of the Section?

I am unable to find the answer in the package-documentation...

Thank you

Comment: How is `\tocsep` defined?

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal complete document and not just snippets?

Comment: related: [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415/579).  (there are a lot of similar questions, but that's the first one i could find easily.)

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the space reserved to typeset the number using the mandatory argument for `\contentslabel`; you are currently using

```
\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{\tocsep}
```

and I assume `\tocsep` is a previously defined length. Simply use a greater value; this might require adjusting some of the other lengths used in your current definition.

As a side note, there seems to be some problem with your definitions, but in the absence of a proper minimal working example, not much more can be done. Please in cases like this one, post always a MWE.