# spacing in list of figures

Tags: spacing

I would like to fix the spacing between the figure number and the name of the figure as shown in the following image: [image: spacing]

The list is auto-generated.
you can find my LaTeX files in the following link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/iz7w3lwr65yds87/fancy.zip
The file to compile is called "fancydissertation.tex"

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Related: [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415/16967)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of the `titletoc` package, just add theses lines to your preamble (the list of tables spacing is not ideal either…):

```
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{figure}[2.2em]{\contentsmargin[2.2em]{0em}\color{untgreen}}{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2.2em}}{\hskip -2.2em}{\color{black}\titlerule*{}\thecontentspage}%

\titlecontents{table}[2em]{\contentsmargin[2em]{0em}\color{untgreen}}{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2em}}{\hskip -2em}{\color{black}\titlerule*{}\thecontentspage}%
```

[image]

[image]