# How to move titles in TOC due to special numbering?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I need special numbering for an article: (e.g. Part 1 should be numbered J4.1, the section below should be J4.1.1). 
I did this with:

```
\renewcommand{\thepart}{J4.\arabic{part}}
\setcounter{part}{0}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{J4.\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{section}{0}
```

The numbering works quite well, but now the position of the titles in the TOC is wrong. Also I get a warning message: Overfull \hbox (14.58316pt too wide) detected.

[image: TOC]

I tried using tocloft and setting the numwidth, but that didn't change anything.

Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass[final]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\thepart}{J4.\arabic{part}}
\setcounter{part}{0}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{J4.\arabic{part}.\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{section}{0}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Part 1}
\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Sub 1 asasdasd}
\subsection{Sub 2 sdlkfjls}
\subsection{Sub 3 ksdfjhj}
\end{document}
```

Do you have any ideas?
Thx!

Comment: Welcome to the site! It would be great if you could provide a small, complete MWE that demonstrates the problem. To get one, make a copy of your file, and then strip it down successively until you have some code that reproduces the problem; once you have that, please add it to your question. Welcome!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) we really need a little more information, at least identification of the documentclass you're using.  even better would be a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: OK, I could fix it with using the tocstyle package. It works now! This helped: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7415/roman-numerals-become-too-wide-in-table-of-contents

Comment: Update: Much nicer now with tocloft: Using the \renewcommand*\cftchapnumwidth{3em}
\renewcommand*\cftsecnumwidth{6em}
\renewcommand*\cftsubsecnumwidth{6em} commands, I can finally change the width of the empty space! Thanks everyone!