# Increase space between numbers and text in List of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents

The template I am using for my thesis doesn't have sufficient space between the numbering of the table of figures and the wording. This results in a table that looks like:

3.17Answer presenter editor prototype. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 120

I've had a look at multiple sources but can't seem to find a solution for increasing the space between the figure number and the first letter, for instance in the example above I'd like more space between the 3.17 and the first letter 'A'.

Is there a way to add some space in?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome, package `tocstyle` can take care of it, other packages can do it as well. Depends on the class in use, please [provide a minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/).

Comment: this question contains the requisite elements: [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415/579)

Answer (score 15):

In the absence of a mwe, this is a  blind shot.

You can use `tocloft` package and change `\cftfignumwidth`

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{2.55em}
```

Change `2.55em` as you wish.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{2.55em}
\begin{document}
  \listoffigures
  \setcounter{chapter}{2}
  \chapter{some}
  \setcounter{figure}{16}
  \begin{figure}[htb]
    \caption{Some figure comes here}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just to make this shot have more of a chance of being made in total darkness, I'd load the `tocloft` package with the option `titles`. That way, the look and feel of the title of the ToC and the LoF is left unchanged.

Comment: If a KOMA class is used, i wouldn't use `tocloft` at all.

Comment: I have a custom floating environment with a custom list made with `\newlistof{excerpt}{loe}{List of Excerpts}`.  Setting `cftfignumwidth` doesn't change a thing, but in this case, I was able to set it with `cftexcerptnumwidth`.  Thanks!