# Modifying spacing in the list of figures

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I am having difficulties with some line spacing in my list of figures.  I am writing a thesis and the requirements for the list of figures table is to have double spacing between entries.  If an entry spans multiple lines, single spacing must be used.  My university has provided a template that I have been utilizing.  The template file for the TOC/LOF/LOT is as follows:

```
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}  

\begin{singlespace}
\renewcommand\contentsname{\normalfont} {\centerline{TABLE OF CONTENTS}}

%\setcounter{tocdepth}{4} % This puts \subsubsection[]{×} in your List of Tables.  The default is 3.


%%%%%%%%%%%%%  Adds Page above the page number in TOC
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{%
\flushright{\normalfont {Page}\par}}



\tableofcontents
%\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
%\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES}

\end{singlespace}

\pagebreak{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                           LIST OF FIGURES
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}  


\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\center\normalfont\MakeUppercase}

\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{-12pt} %% Positions the LOF title vertically to match the chapter titles
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitleskip}{12pt}


\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{%
\\[4em]\mbox{}\hspace{2pt}FIGURE\hfill{\normalfont Page}\vskip\baselineskip}



\begingroup


\begin{center}
\begin{singlespace}



%% These values make the lof table entries appear double spaced between.


\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0.4cm}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.30cm}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{0.30cm}
\setlength{\cftbeforefigskip}{0.4cm}
\setlength{\cftbeforetabskip}{0.4cm} 



\listoffigures

\end{singlespace}
\end{center}

\pagebreak{}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                           lIST OF TABLES
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF TABLES}  

\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\center\normalfont\MakeUppercase}

\setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{-12pt} %% Positions the LOT title vertically to match the chapter titles

\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitleskip}{12pt}


\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{%
\\[4em]\mbox{}\hspace{4pt}TABLE\hfill{\normalfont Page}\vskip\baselineskip}

\begin{center}
\begin{singlespace}

%% These values make the lot table entries appear double spaced between.
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0.4cm}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.30cm}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{0.30cm}
\setlength{\cftbeforefigskip}{0.4cm}
\setlength{\cftbeforetabskip}{0.4cm}

\listoftables 

\end{singlespace}
\end{center}
\endgroup
\pagebreak{}  % Need this for the pagenumbering to be correct.
```

This template has worked great with one exception.  In my list of figure, some of the figure numbers overlap the figure title.  After searching around the forums, I found the following solution at [How to modify the space between the numbers and text of sectioning titles in the table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33841/how-to-modify-the-space-between-the-numbers-and-text-of-sectioning-titles-in-the).

```
\makeatletter
     \renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3.2em}}
\makeatother
```

Adding this command to the "LIST OF FIGURES" section fixed the spacing issue between the figure number and figure description within my list of figures.  Unfortunately, after adding this command, the \setlength commands that allowed the list of figures to be double spaced between entries and single space within each entry no longer seems to work.  Instead the whole list of figures table now appears with single spacing.  I have been searching the forums, but I have not been able to figure out why this is happening.  Note, I cannot simply change it to double spacing since the spacing within each entry that spans more than one line must be single spaced.

Why are the \setlength commands no longer working when the \@dottedtocline command is added?  Is there a way to add the \@dottedtocline command such that the \setlength commands will still work?  I do not have much experience yet working with latex and any advice regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Sincerely,

Aaron

Comment: The university provides a template that does not follow the style guide? Does that make sense?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) (<- Link) that makes the prolem reproducable for us? Your question is quite lengthy, but no compilble code is present, making it hrd to understand.

Comment: try with `{\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}\listoffigures}`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Johannes and Touhmi for your input.  Touhami, I tried entering your command, but that didn't seem to work for me.  However, I did find a simple solution at [Increase space between numbers and text in List of Figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235191/increase-space-between-numbers-and-text-in-list-of-figures).

Basically, I just used

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{2.55em}
```

at the beginning of the document to adjust the spacing between my figures numbers and titles in the table of figures.  This was used in place of

```
\makeatletter
     \renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3.2em}}
\makeatother
```

which, was somehow messing up the desired line spacing in my table of figures.

Aaron