# Space between number and item in List of Listings

Tags: table-of-contents, minted

I have a report with several code blocks (made with `minted`), and I would like to have a List of Listings to ease searching. However, currently the number and the caption of the elements are overlapping in the list, as seen in the following image, particularly in codes 5.3.10, 5.3.11 and so on.

[image]

I have seen some solutions out there, but they mess up with my previous configuration (what is proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235191/increase-space-between-numbers-and-text-in-list-of-figures) disables the sectioning, for example making the Code 5.3.9 appear as Code 41 both in the caption and the list of listings).

Is there any other way to do it?

Currently, my `minted` environments, captions and list of listings are defined this way:

```
% THIS WAS THE PREVIOUS SOLUTION, BUT IT DISABLED SECTIONING
% \usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
% \newlistof{listing}{lol}{Índice de códigos}
% \setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{2.55em}
% \setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{2.55em}
% \setlength{\cftlistingnumwidth}{2.55em}

% CURRENT CONFIGURATIONS
\usepackage[section]{minted}
\setminted{xleftmargin=2em,
bgcolor=lightgray!15,
autogobble=true,
numbers=left,
frame=lines, 
framesep=2mm,
baselinestretch=1.2,
fontsize=\small,
breaklines=true,
breakanywhere}
\newenvironment{code}{\captionsetup{type=listing}}{}
\SetupFloatingEnvironment{listing}{name=Código}
\renewcommand{\listingscaption}{Código}
\renewcommand{\listoflistingscaption}{Índice de códigos}
```

If more information is needed please don't hesitate to ask. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The actual formatting is done by \numberline and \l@listings.  Nothing else really matters.

Comment: This question may help.  Although the problem presented is in the main TOC, the principle should be the same.  [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415)

Comment: @JohnKormylo Would you be able to expand on this and possibly propose an answer?

Comment: 1)  I can't use minted (no shell escapes).  2) All you have here is a code fragment.  You  might find https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410194/positioning-list-in-list-of-figures/410240?r=SearchResults&s=3|10.5104#410240 interesting, but most people prefer to use packages like titletoc (which I find even harder to use than \l@figure etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `\usepackage[tocindentauto]{tocstyle}` to the preamble fixed the problem.

Thanks to [barbara beeton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/579/barbara-beeton) for pointing [a helping question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415) in the [comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495172/space-between-number-and-item-in-list-of-listings#comment1250316_495172)!