# Overlapping part numbering in table of contents

Tags: tables, memoir, roman-numerals

I'm having a few problems with my 'Table of Contents' as it the numbering interferes with the chapter and part labels.

I've added a screenshot of the problem [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hed8l.png)

I would prefer to keep the roman numbering.

`\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}
.
.
\begin{document}
.
.
\end{document}`

Comment: this seems to cover the same territory: [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415/579)

Comment: @barbarabeeton - The "twist" in this posting is that the OP is using the `memoir` document class, which provides its own macros for modifying and customizing the look of the ToC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using the `memoir` document class, you could issue the command

```
\setlength\cftpartnumwidth{3em}
```

in the preamble. This instruction increases the width of the block that's set aside for the `part`-level Roman numerals in the ToC. For a consistent appearance, you should probably also provide the instructions

```
\setlength\cftchapternumwidth{3em}
\setlength\cftsectionindent{3em}
```

in the preamble.