# list of figures space after figure name?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I am using a template to write my  thesis and I got something like that which is shown in the image when it automatically generates list of figures. How can I fix that? I am also enclosing the part which I believe is the source of problem in the class file.

[image: the unpleasent thing:)]

```
\newcommand\listoffigures{%
\if@twocolumn
  \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
\else
  \@restonecolfalse
\fi
\chapter{\listfigurename}%
\vspace{10pt}
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
          {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
\@starttoc{lof}%
\if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
}
```

All the packages I use is:

```
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{picins}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
```

There is also something defined like this on the beginning of the latex class file that I am using.

```
  \def\ext@figure{lof}
```

Please show me which parts do I need to change in order to give some space between figure names and the explanations? I am good at programming but no clue about latex at all. Please state which parts do I need to change clearly.

A working example of the template for thesis can be downloaded from below:

http://www.students.graduate.ucf.edu/WorkArea/DownloadAsset.aspx?id=1464

(I have edited the post according to the comments)

Thanks

Comment: This is similar in nature to: [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415/5764) You need to provide the community with more details on how you create the LoF entries with the preceding `Figure ` reference.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The look of List of Figures shown in the screenshot isn't what "basic" LaTeX would produce. Please state which packages and/or own preamble commands you're employing.

Comment: Can you provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)? It should be something that replicates your document layout, but be very minimal. In your case, perhaps just a single figure and a LoF that shows your `Figure` prefix and the gap between the number and caption (in the LoF). You may have to set the counters like `\setcounter{figure}{20}` in order to get an appropriately sized (big) figure number, but still. The current code snippets don't really provide enough context.

Comment: Checkout the `tocloft` package (for the documentation try `texdoc tocloft`)