# Overlapping numbers and titles in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

How can i change formatting of the table of contents to avoid section numbering and section title to overlap?

Document:

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,notitlepage]{book}

% Use Heuristica Font
\usepackage{heuristica}
\usepackage[heuristica,vvarbb,bigdelims]{newtxmath}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{\textosf{#1}}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Part one}

\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}


\section{Chapter Hi}
\section{Chapter Hi}
\section{Chapter Hi}
\section{Chapter Hi}
\section{Chapter Hi}
\section{Chapter Hi}
\section{Chapter Hi}
\section{Chapter Hi}
\section{Chapter Hi}
\section{Chapter Hi}

\end{document}
```

Example output:
[image: Output example]

Comment: Please provide the minimal code that generates this wrong output. I assume that a wrong `\thesection` etc. command is applied or a misused of `tocloft` features

Comment: Also, [Welcome to LaTeX! Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: potentiial duplicate: [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415).  (arabic numerals are no different from roman numerals in this respect.)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have added code and a new example screenshot. It looks like the heuristica font/package is causing the issue.

Comment: @NichlasH.: Thanks -- see the (possible) answer please.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The space needed by the section number(s) is too small. Using `tocloft` this spacing can be controlled by the length register `\cftsecnumwidth`, adding some value with `\addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{10pt}` will improve the spacing.

The value of `10pt` can be changed of course.

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,notitlepage]{book}

% Use Heuristica Font
\usepackage{heuristica}
\usepackage[heuristica,vvarbb,bigdelims]{newtxmath}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{\textosf{#1}}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{10pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Part one}

\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}
\chapter{Chapter Oh}


\section{Chapter Hi}
\section{Chapter Hi}
\section{Chapter Hi}
\section{Chapter Hi}
\section{Chapter Hi}
\section{Chapter Hi}
\section{Chapter Hi}
\section{Chapter Hi}
\section{Chapter Hi}
\section{Chapter Hi}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That will work well into the third and fourth digit chapter numbers (i hope to end the document well before that!). Also thanks for hinting `tocloft`, looks like it has some interresting options.

Comment: @NichlasH.: You can change the value of 10pt to 'anything' -- as you wish.

Comment: Yes, I'll test it out and find what works for my document. I'm sorry that I don't have anough points (yet) to upvote your answer.

Comment: @NichlasH.: That's alright. You can accept it later on anyway ;-)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Above like 10-20pt it stops changing the width