# Let the section of the part recount

Tags: numbering

I want every part have a new counter.

```
\documentclass[UTF8,10pt,a4paper]{article}
\author{wsy}
\title{test}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\part{part $1$}
\section{part 1, section 1}
\part{part $2$}
\section{  how to make this section label become 1}
 %(* now  it is 1 *)
\end{document}
```

Comment: `article`  does not provide chapters. Are you looking for `report` class?

Comment: To the actual problem: `\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{section}{part}
`

Comment: this is useful, but have a problem.  section name and content is partial overlap

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296545/overlapping-numbers-and-titles-in-toc

Answer (score 0):

With `chngcntr` it's easy:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithin*{section}{part}

\author{wsy}
\title{test}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\part{part 1}
\section{part 1, section 1}

\part{part 2}
\section{how to make this section label become 1}

\end{document}
```

Note `\counterwithin*`, so the definition of `\thesection` is not changed.

[image]

If you want arabic numbers for parts and sections in the style `part.section`, you can do like

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}
\counterwithin{section}{part}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\l@section}{1.5em}{2em}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\l@subsection}{1.5em}{2em}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\l@subsection}{2.3em}{2.8em}{}{}
\makeatother

\author{wsy}
\title{test}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\part{part 1}
\section{part 1, section 1}
\subsection{what's this}

\part{part 2}
\section{how to make this section label become 1}

\end{document}
```

Similar modifications are needed if you also have subsubsections in the table of contents.

[image]