# Overlapping to fix in my table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

In my table of contents, I observe that headings numbers nearly overlap titles of sections, as illustrated below.

[image]

What could I do to solve that? This is a MWE (a little bit long because I don't know exactly if I did not make any mistake) :

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,%
               twoside=semi,%
               headings=small,%
               chapterprefix=true,%
               listof=flat]%
{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\stepcounter{secnumdepth}
\stepcounter{tocdepth}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{chronosys}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\onehalfspacing


\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
%\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage[marginparsep=8pt,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}


\newcounter{qcounter}


\usepackage{hyperref}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}}}


\date{}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter



\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\part{Une partie}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}


\part{Une partie}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum


\part{Une partie}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}


\part{Une partie}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum


\part{Une partie}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum

\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum

\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum

\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum


\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum


\part{Une partie}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum


\part{Une partie}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\lipsum
\section{Une section}
\lipsum
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\lipsum





\end{document}
```

Comment: Your  document is empty, there is nothing to overlap then ;-)

Comment: ... yes it is: I can't send you my whole thesis. Reason why I posted a picture. Isn't that enough?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296545 or maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7853

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Bad idea. Do NOT use `tocloft` with KOMA.

Comment: @domi Well, typically people here expect that you provide a minimal and yet complete example code so that it's easy to help and that there is less chance of misunderstanding. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296545 for example.

Comment: @TeXnician Ok ok :): Another try: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7415 (`tocstyle`). Actually, I didn't see the `scrbook` due to the formatting in the question code :).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Also a bad idea. `tocstyle` is beta. There is `tocbasic`.

Comment: @TeXnician I give up :).

Comment: @domi: What's the point in posting the screenshot of your real code outcome and providing a document code that does not even generate output?

Comment: We recently had a similar question. take a look at `tocindent` or something like that in the manual.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Where's `tocindent` from? It's not on TL 2017

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner 'tocloft' works and my problem is solved.

Comment: Since all helpers here can surely reproduce that output, i don't think there is a real need to see a minimal working example here. The class in use is most important. Knowing the OP is unable to provide a MWE due to a lack of knowledge, why bother asking for one?

Comment: You should NOT use `tocloft` with KOMA. Usually `listof=flat` already solves the issue. On the other hand there's `tocbasic` with `\setuptoc{toc}{dynnumwidth=true}`.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Sorry, I don't think you should support pure laziness

Comment: @Christian Hupfer Please, let me take some time to understand how that works and I'll come back to you with another mwe. I'm currently rebuilding my preamble. "Laziness"? I'll send you too both a mwe and my CV.

Comment: Why do you remove the MWE that shows your problem with some useless junk of code?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Did you mean `replace` instead of `remove`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, i did.

Comment: @Johannes_B I did it because I provided you a new mwe and because I was not sure that there was not some error in my preamble.

Answer (score 3):

The KOMA-Script classes load package `tocbasic` automatically. So it should be used to format the ToC and its entries. (Do not use `tocloft`! And package `tocstyle` will never leave the beta status, AFAIK it is not developed anymore.)

There are different ways to avoid the overlapping.

You could use option **`toc=flat`**:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,%
               twoside=semi,%
               headings=small,%
               chapterprefix=true,%
               listof=flat,%
               toc=flat,% <- added
              ]%
{scrbook}[2017/01/03]

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage[marginparsep=8pt,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subsubsectiontocdepth}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subsubsectionnumdepth}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\part{Une partie}
\blindtext
\blinddocument
\setcounter{chapter}{33}% only for the example
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\blindtext
\setcounter{section}{17}% only for the example
\section{Une section}
\blindtext
\setcounter{subsection}{13}% only for the example
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\blindtext
\setcounter{subsubsection}{10}% only for the example
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get

[image]

Or you could use **`\RedeclareSectionCommands[tocdynnumwidth=true]{...}`**:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,%
               twoside=semi,%
               headings=small,%
               chapterprefix=true,%
               listof=flat,%
              ]%
{scrbook}[2017/01/03]
\RedeclareSectionCommands[tocdynnumwidth=true]
  {chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection}% <- added

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage[marginparsep=8pt,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subsubsectiontocdepth}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subsubsectionnumdepth}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\part{Une partie}
\blindtext
\blinddocument
\setcounter{chapter}{33}% only for the example
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\blindtext
\setcounter{section}{17}% only for the example
\section{Une section}
\blindtext
\setcounter{subsection}{13}% only for the example
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\blindtext
\setcounter{subsubsection}{10}% only for the example
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get

[image]

Or you can adjust `numwidth` manuelly using **`\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocnumwidth=...]{...}`:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,%
               twoside=semi,%
               headings=small,%
               chapterprefix=true,%
               listof=flat,%
              ]%
{scrbook}[2017/01/03]
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocnumwidth=2em]{chapter}% <- added
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocnumwidth=3em]{section}% <- added
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocnumwidth=4.1em]{subsection}% <- added
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocnumwidth=5.3em]{subsubsection}% <- added

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage[marginparsep=8pt,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subsubsectiontocdepth}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subsubsectionnumdepth}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\part{Une partie}
\blindtext
\blinddocument
\setcounter{chapter}{33}% only for the example
\chapter{Un chapitre}
\blindtext
\setcounter{section}{17}% only for the example
\section{Une section}
\blindtext
\setcounter{subsection}{13}% only for the example
\subsection{Une sous-section}
\blindtext
\setcounter{subsubsection}{10}% only for the example
\subsubsection{Une sous-sous-section}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Run two times to get:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As you're using a KOMA-Script class you should not use `tocloft`. `tocloft` should give you a warning if you load it with KOMA.

Usually you're done with `toc=flat`. But you should consider to compile multiple times.

Another option: `tocstyle`, which is currently (and probably forever) beta, is part of the KOMA bundle.

Comment: @esdd You're right, `toc=flat` was the option.