# Overlapping numbers and titles in toc with hausarbeit-jura

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm using the document class [hausarbeit-jura](https://github.com/sieversMartin/hausarbeit-jura) (a document class for jura student papers).

The number of my 8th section (roman numbering "VIII") overlaps with the title of the section in the table of contents.

I already had a look at [Overlapping numbers and titles in toc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/296736/128663) but when I add `\addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{10pt}` to my document I get the error message:

```
Undefined control sequence \addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{10pt}
Missing number, treated as zero \section
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) \section
```

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,utf8,headline,headlinetitlepageleft,nosuperscriptedition]{hausarbeit-jura}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{10pt}
\section{TEXT}
\section{TEXT}
\section{TEXT}
\section{TEXT}
\section{TEXT}
\section{TEXT}
\section{TEXT}
\section{TEXT}
\section{TEXT}

\end{document}
```

Result looks like this:
[image]

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks to everyone in advance! :-)

Comment: Did you compile twice? For `\cftsecnumwidth` you need another package (`tocloft` iirc).

Comment: Yes, I was missing the package! Thanks so far! Now my subthree, subfour and other sections are not intended correctly. I will  try it myself first.

Comment: No need to load `tocloft`. You can use `\AtBeginDocument{\sectionnumwidth=2cm}` somewhere in your preamble. Same should be true for other levels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class does

```
\settowidth{\sectionnumwidth}{III.\ }
```

which is insufficient for accommodating VIII. You can use `VIII` instead.

```
%\UseRawInputEncoding % uncomment for TeX Live 2018

\documentclass[
  12pt,
  utf8,
  headline,
  headlinetitlepageleft,
  nosuperscriptedition
]{hausarbeit-jura}

\AtBeginDocument{\settowidth{\sectionnumwidth}{VIII.\ }}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{TEXT}
\section{TEXT}
\section{TEXT}
\section{TEXT}
\section{TEXT}
\section{TEXT}
\section{TEXT}
\section{TEXT}
\section{TEXT}

\end{document}
```

The first line should be uncommented if TeX Live 2018 (more precisely LaTeX 2018-04-01), as the class has not yet been updated for UTF-8 support by default.

[image]

Comment: That solved the problem. Thank you very much!