# More than 100 figures causing jumble of text in list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents

I have posted a minimal working example highlighting my issue.  I prefer my figures to be numbered related to section, i.e. 1.1, 1.2 instead of 1,2,3,4 etc.  However, when more than 100 figures are in play it causes a 5 digit entry in the LOF that jumbles into the caption.

Changing the font to the default from fourier helps, but is extremely ugly (I'm working on a 500 page document right now, and it ruins it immediately).  Changing the numbering style also helps, but I have many sections and the subformatting is helpful.  Can anyone advise?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation

\usepackage{fourier} % Use the Adobe Utopia font for the document - comment this line to return to the LaTeX default

\usepackage{amsmath} % Math packages that are default to LaTeX
    \numberwithin{figure}{section} % Number figures within sections (i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4)

% Note that more than 100 figures causes a jumble of text in the list of figures.  This is compounded by using the hyperref package as well.
% Commenting the fourier package eases the issue a little bit but the default font is very ugly and ruins my documents the as soon as I implement it.
% Finally I prefer my figures to be numbered as indicated above and believe it is important to leave the figures in this format.

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section{Section 1}

% Below is the same figure code repeated 210 times and then \end{document}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\clearpage




\end{document}
```

Comment: this question deals with the equivalent problem in a toc: [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415)

Answer (score 12):

I increased the size of the field from 2.3em to 3em.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation

\usepackage{fourier} % Use the Adobe Utopia font for the document - comment this line to return to the LaTeX default

\usepackage{amsmath} % Math packages that are default to LaTeX
    \numberwithin{figure}{section} % Number figures within sections (i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4)

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3em}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section{Section 1}

% Below is the same figure code repeated 210 times and then \end{document}

\setcounter{figure}{100}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: This did work immediately and I thank you very much.