# missing space on appendix section in the toc

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, appendices

This is my code for the appendix, and it is working fine except for on the table of contents, the it is missing a space after the equations.

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage[md]{titlesec}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb} 


\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{floatpag}
\floatpagestyle{plain}

\usepackage[verbose]{cite}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{breakurl}


\usepackage{setspace}%double spacing


\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}%margins


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
        axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
        axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
        axis line style={<->}, % arrows on the axis
        xlabel={$x$},          % default put x on x-axis
        ylabel={$y$},          % default put y on y-axis
    },
    cmhplot/.style={color=black,mark=none,line width=1pt,<->},
    soldot/.style={color=black,only marks,mark=*},
    holdot/.style={color=black,fill=white,only marks,mark=*},
}
\tikzset{>=stealth}




\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering\normalfont\large}{CHAPTER \arabic{chapter}}{0pt}{}{}
\titleformat*{\section}{\centering\bfseries\large}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\bfseries\large}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\large}


\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{2\baselineskip}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{0pt}{1em} 

\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for parts
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}


\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{}


\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\normalsize\normalfont} 
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalsize\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\normalsize\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalsize\normalfont}


\cftsetindents{chapter}{.25in}{.25in}
\cftsetindents{section}{.5in}{.25in}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{.75in}{.5in}
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{1in}{.5in}

\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip} 
\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip}

\newenvironment{MyFigure}[1][]{\begin{figure}[#1]\vspace{\baselineskip}}{\vspace{\baselineskip}\end{figure}}%puts spacing before figuress


\doublespacing %double space
\raggedbottom 

\begin{document}


\chapter*{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
    \vspace{-4\baselineskip}
    \tableofcontents



\cleardoublepage
\chapter*{LIST OF FIGURES}
\vspace{-4\baselineskip}
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}LIST OF FIGURES}
\cleardoublepage

\chapter*{LIST OF SYMBOLS}
%\vspace{-6\baselineskip}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}LIST OF SYMBOLS}
\subfile{sections/Los}

\chapter*{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
%\vspace{-6\baselineskip}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
\subfile{sections/Loa}


\cleardoublepage
\cleardoublepage
\large
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}   

\addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\contentsline{part}{CHAPTER}{}}

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\label{Intro}
\section{Background}
\label{Backgrnd}
\subfile{Sections/Background}

\section{Questions}
\label{Quest}
\subfile{Sections/quest}

\section{Limitations}
\label{Limit}
\subfile{Sections/Limit}

\chapter{RELATED WORKS}
\label{RelWorks}
\subfile{Sections/Relworks}

\chapter{METHODOLOGY}
\label{Method}
\subfile{Sections/Methodology}

\chapter{RESULTS}
\label{Result}
\subfile{Sections/Result}

\chapter{CONCLUSION}
\label{Conclusion}
\subfile{Sections/conclusion}


\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}REFERENCES}
\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand\bibname{REFERENCES}
\setstretch{1} %this single spaces within bib entries, but keeps double spaces between entries

\bibliography{ref}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\nocite{*}
%\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\contentsline{part}{APPENDIX }{}}
\appendix
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering\normalfont\large}{APPENDIX  \Alph{chapter}}{0pt}{}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter }{0pt}{250pt}{40pt}
\chapter{Equations }
\label{eqn}
\subfile{Sections/Equation}
\clearpage
%\chapter[\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}FINAL APPENDIX TITLE]{ Equation}%the last appendix needs to be added strangely


\clearpage
%\begin{lstlisting}
%LST LISTING IS HELPFUL FOR CODE
%\end{lstlisting}
%\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
\chapter*{VITA}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{VITA}
\large
\subfile{Sections/Vita}
\paragraph{}
\end{document}
```

How do I fix the space?
[image]

Comment: I don't see the code that generates the ToC there. Apparently, `\thesection` etc. is redefined to be something like `A.\arabic{section}`. In a normal document class there should be enough space for `A` and some small number. Alas, you don't show anything useful here, in my point of view

Comment: `tocloft` and `titlesec` together are not really recommended

Comment: you're not using roman numerals, but the width problem is the same: [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7415/roman-numerals-become-too-wide-in-table-of-contents)