# Appendix dotted leader and spacing in the title of appendix

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, appendices, letterspacing

Here is how my appendix looks like in TOC, How do I fix the spacing in the title and the dot leader of the Appendix? I can fix this by using tocstyle=auto, but when I do that it messes up my toc in a different way.

[image: Appendix]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[]{report} 

\usepackage[md]{titlesec} %required for section titles
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
%\usepackage[tocindentauto]{tocstyle}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb} %more symbols

\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{floatpag}
\floatpagestyle{plain}


\usepackage[verbose]{cite} 
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{breakurl}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{wrapfig, framed, caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}%margins
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}% LoF
\makeatother
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering\normalfont\large}{CHAPTER \arabic{chapter}}{0pt}{}{} %format of chapter & section headings
\titleformat*{\section}{\centering\bfseries\large}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\bfseries\large}%see guidelines for what is allowed and what is not
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\large}%try really hard not to use subsubsubsections


\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{0pt}%spacing between headings
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{2\baselineskip}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{0pt}{1em} %this removes the vertical space before each \paragraph{}

\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\normalsize\normalfont} 
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalsize\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\normalsize\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalsize\normalfont}

\cftsetindents{chapter}{.25in}{.25in}
\cftsetindents{section}{.5in}{.25in}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{.75in}{.5in}
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{1in}{.5in}

\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip} 
\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecafterpnum{\vskip-.5\baselineskip}


\doublespacing 
\raggedbottom 

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}

    \large

    \vspace*{2in}
    J\\
    \vspace{2in}
    By\\
    J
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}
    \begin{center}
    \vspace*{2in}
    \vspace{1in}
    By\\~\\
    J\\
    \vspace*{1in}
    A Thesis \\~\\~\\~\\

    \end{center}
    \chapter*{}
    \begin{center}
    \vfill
    Copyright \copyright\ 2017

    \bigskip

    By J

    \bigskip

    All Rights Reserved
    \vfill
    \end{center}
    \chapter*{ABSTRACT}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}ABSTRACT}
    \large
    \paragraph{O}

    \chapter*{ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}ACKNOWLEDGMENTS}
    %\subfile{sections/Acknowledge}

    \chapter*{DEDICATION}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}DEDICATION}
    %\subfile{sections/Dedication}


    \vspace{-6\baselineskip}
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS} 
    \tableofcontents

    \vspace{-4\baselineskip}
    \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
    \listoffigures
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}LIST OF FIGURES}

    \chapter*{LIST OF SYMBOLS}
    %\vspace{-6\baselineskip}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}LIST OF SYMBOLS}
    %\subfile{sections/Los}

    \chapter*{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
    %\vspace{-6\baselineskip}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
    %\subfile{sections/Loa}

    \cleardoublepage
    \cleardoublepage
    \large
    \clearpage
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}


\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\label{Intro}
\section{Background}
\label{Backgrnd}
%\subfile{Sections/Background}

\section{Questions and Limitations}
\label{Quest}
%\subfile{Sections/quest}

\chapter{RELATED WORKS}
\label{RelWorks}
%\subfile{Sections/Relworks}

\chapter{METHODOLOGY}
\label{Method}
%\subfile{Sections/Methodology}

\chapter{RESULTS}
\label{Result}
%\subfile{Sections/Result}

\chapter{CONCLUSION}
\label{Conclusion}
%\subfile{Sections/conclusion}


\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}REFERENCES}
\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand\bibname{REFERENCES}
\setstretch{1} 


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{100000000} 
\makeatother

\addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\contentsline{part}{APPENDIX }{}}

\appendix
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering\normalfont\large}{APPENDIX  \Alph{chapter}}{0pt}{}{}
\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{\def\string\@dotsep{10}}  
\makeatother
\chapter{Equations }
\label{eqn}
%\subfile{Sections/Equation}
\clearpage

\chapter*{VITA}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{VITA}
\large
%\subfile{Sections/Vita}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [perhaps related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7415/roman-numerals-become-too-wide-in-table-of-contents)

Comment: It is similar, but can't find the solution to my problem based on the suggestions there.