# TOC: Overlapping point and text

Tags: table-of-contents

I generate a the table of contents with latex, but at one position it looks like on this image:

[image]

The "point" and the text are overlapping. Can this somehow be avoided?

Thank you

Comment: This can be avoided but the solution might depend strongly on the document class.

Comment: We have this question basically every other day...

Comment: Thanks, you are right: I solved it by using "\usepackage[tocindentauto]{tocstyle}" (solution from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7423/119588 )