# cftXpresnum overlapping with heading

Tags: tocloft

As per the `tocloft` package documentation, we should be able to use `\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{something}` to insert some text before the section number in the table of contents (for example, should work for list of tables, list of figures, and a custom list using `\newlistof`).

However, when I use that command the I want to insert before the section heading entry in the table of contents overlaps with the section heading text. See MWE. Am I missing something here? I did not immediately see an answer to address this, specifically as to whether or not the `\cftsecpresnum` command from the `tocloft` works or not. As per below I would have to use `\cftsecindent` as a work around, but that was not mentioned in the package documentation and not sure if that is the intent.

Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{Something }

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{what}
  Bananas

\section{is the deal}
  Apples

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415/5764)

Comment: That question would have provided me with a solution, and in my mind is the same. But is it acknowledged that it isn't specified (or isn't required to be specified) in the documentation? I have similar comment below as well...how would this be achieved for a custom list? Or new question?

Comment: I agree that the link provided gives an answer to the question I asked. I would not object if this question is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to increase the value if `\cftsecnumwidth`. here is a solution, using `calc`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{Something }
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{\widthof{Something\hspace{2.5em}}}
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{what}
  Bananas

\section{is the deal}
  Apples

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That would work and I didn't know/think of `calc`...is there a way to adjust the equivalent of `\cftsecnumwidth` for a custom list or would that be a new question?

Comment: There are  ways, with  `enumitem`, which depend on the list type. I think it's better to ask a new question.