# Hi. I have the following problem in my list of figures in latex. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Tags: table-of-contents

[image]This is the code used:

\newpage
{\setstretch{1.0} 
\listoffigures}

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX. What is your problem? You didn't show a minimal working example yet.

Comment: It’s a bit hard to understand your question. Can you explain what the problem is, and can you provide a full minimal working example (“MWE”), ie the code of a complete LaTeX document, based on a shortened version of your document, so that we can directly try it out to help find your issue.

Comment: This question deals with a very similar problem: overprinting of text by too-wide numbers: [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415)

Answer (score 1):

It would be very helpful to know at least the class you are using. Also you could have said what your problem is. So, I'm having to guess that you want more space for the figure numbers. You can use the `tocloft` package for this.

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{5em} % choose the length to suit you (default is 2.3em)
```

Read the documentation (`< texdoc tocloft`) for all information about the package.