# How do I create space between numbers and text in the list of figures

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

[image]

Hello, I need more space between numbers and text in LoF. How do I do that??

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  What document class are you using?  The answer may differ depending on that.  A MWE would help -- that's a brief compilable example that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` that exhibits the problem.

Comment: You could temporarily redefine `\numberline` to use a specific width: `\hbox to <width> {#1\hfill}`.  Normally this width is passed by `\@dottedtocline` which is called in `\l@figure`

Comment: Most "Tables" are constructed in a similar manner.  This may help: [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `tocloft` package.

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{3em} % change the 3em to suit
```

The `\cftfignumwidth` is the space available for typesetting the figure number. There are other lengths for other kinds of numbers (such as `\section` or tables). Read the manual `texdoc tocloft` for more information.