# Table of contentes: title overlaping

Tags: table-of-contents

I am using this code for table of contents,

```
\tableofcontents{}
```

but for the sections where I apply

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Appendix \Alph{section}}
\section{- Summary statistics by year}
```

the reference in the table of contents appears overlapped, like:

[image]

Can you please help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Same problem here.  Potential duplicate: [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `tocloft` package. For example as in the MWE below:

```
% tocappprob.tex  SE 552614

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Conclusion}

\appendix
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Appendix \Alph{section}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{6em}} % increase the space for section numbers
\section{Statistics}

\end{document}
```

Apart from the package the key line is the `\addtocontents{toc}{...}` which inserts the command in the ToC to increase the space for your appendix section numbers.

It would have been helpful if you had provided an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`. I had to guess as to what your code might look like and I think got it wrong. Anyway, `tocloft` and `\addtocontents{toc}{...}` should be what you need.

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfectly.