# memoir: Roman chapters in ToC

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, memoir, roman-numerals

When I set

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
```

I can't figure out how to increase the space in the toc between 'VIII'/'XIII'/'XIV' and the section title.  (shorter Roman numbers fit nicely.)  I need at least another 1ex, or possibly 1em, more space for the chapter number in the toc.  (Maybe the default should be just a little spacier??)

I read chapter 9 of the memoir manual a few times, but

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{20em}
\makeatother
```

did not work.  What is the right way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`memoir`](//ctan.org/pkg/memoir) implements a similar setup to what is provided by [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) natively. So, you need to adjust the lengths `\cftchapternumwidth` (and lower levels, possibly, like `\cftsectionnumwidth`) to give the Roman numerals a little more space in the ToC.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\setlength{\cftchapternumwidth}{3em}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\sloppy% Just for this example
\chapter{First chapter}\lipsum[1-50]
\chapter{Second chapter}\lipsum[1-50]
\chapter{Third chapter}\lipsum[1-50]
\chapter{Fourth chapter}\lipsum[1-50]
\chapter{Fifth chapter}\lipsum[1-50]
\chapter{Sixth chapter}\lipsum[1-50]
\chapter{Seventh chapter}\lipsum[1-50]
\chapter{Eighth chapter}\lipsum[1-50]
\chapter{Ninth chapter}\lipsum[1-50]
\chapter{Tenth chapter}\lipsum[1-50]
\chapter{Eleventh chapter}\lipsum[1-50]
\chapter{Twelfth chapter}\lipsum[1-50]
\chapter{Thirteenth chapter}\lipsum[1-50]
\chapter{Fourteenth chapter}\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```