# Table of contents not showing correctly

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

Anyone knows how to solve this? The problem is that the number is very close to the title when the number reaches 10. I will add an image to reference this. Thanks in advance!

[image]

These are all the packages (and the type of document) I used:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{cite} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[final]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{subfiles}
```

NOTE: This [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7415/roman-numerals-become-too-wide-in-table-of-contents) is related but that solution doesn't work perfectly because it changes the spacing and removes the period after the number. I only want to change that space between number and title. Thanks!

[image]

EDIT: Added MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{cite} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[final]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{.5em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.35}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength\headheight{0pt} 
\begin{center}
        {\Large\bfseries Resume\par}
        \vspace{0.5cm}
\end{center}

\tableofcontents
\pagebreak

\section{A}
\section{B}
\section{C}
\section{D}
\section{E}
\section{F}
\section{G}
\section{H}
\section{I}
\section{J}
\section{K}
\section{L}
\section{M}

\end{document}
```

This will display:

[image]

Comment: How does the rest of your code look?

Comment: You mention a solution to adifferent question, but this question has a total of 7 different answers. Which of them did you try? Please also prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get.

Comment: Something along the lines of `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftsecaftersnum{.}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecaftersnum{.}
\renewcommand*\cftsecnumwidth{2em}` sould work. (not tested)

Comment: Which indentation are you referring to, specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution remains the same as in [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415/5764), except for some shuffling of the package loading:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{3em}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\section{A}
\subsection{AA}
\section{B}
\section{C}
\section{D}
\section{E}
\section{F}
\section{G}
\section{H}
\section{I}
\section{J}
\section{K}
\section{L}
\section{M}

\end{document}
```

---

You can also adjust the spacing manually by patching `\l@section`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}% <cmd>
  {1.5em}% <search>
  {2em}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

Comment: The spacing is completely separate from the indentation. You can adjust `\baselinestretch` or use [`setspace`](//ctan.org/pkg/setspace) (latter is preferred).

Comment: @santilococo: You can use your previous settings: `\setlength{\parskip}{.5em} \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.35}` if you wish.

Comment: @santilococo: [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) does manage all of the ToC content; even setting the vertical spacing between certain elements. Try adding `\setlength{\cftparskip}{.5em} \addtolength{\cftbeforesecskip}{.5em}` as part of your settings. It specifies the `\parskip` within the ToC and the skip before a section. You can adjust it to suit your needs.

Comment: @santilococo: I've added an addendum to my answer showing how to change the default spacing from `1.5em` for the number to `2em`. You can use that option if all the other settings are giving you issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `tocloft` package and `\cftsecnumwidth` to change the space for section numbers in the ToC.

**EDIT**

Changed the answer to meet the OP's desire (in a comment) to have extra space between the ToC entries.

```
% tocnumprob.tex rev 2 SE 575762 

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{comment}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{name=\section}[block]
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection~~#1}{1em}{}[
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\thesection~#1}]
\end{comment}

\usepackage{tocloft}
%\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{3.5em}  % change this to suit more space for section numbers
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{%    % don't put section numbers in a box
  {\@cftbsnum #1\@cftasnum\hfil}\@cftasnumb}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{\hspace{1em}} % change this to suit space after section number

\setlength{\cftparskip}{\baselineskip} % put more space between entries

\begin{document}
    
\tableofcontents 
\pagebreak

\section{A}
\section{B}
\section{C}
\section{D}
\section{E}
\section{F}
\section{G}
\section{H}
\section{I}
\section{J}
\section{K}
\section{L}
\section{M}
\subsection{Subsection}
\end{document}

\section{Fisrt}
\setcounter{section}{98999}
\section{section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @santilococo What spacing? What original?

Comment: @santilococo I have updated my answer to deal with your latest request. --- GOM