# How to use the section command and keep a clear table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, section-titles, renewcommand

I want to change the section formatting to a longer one but the table of contents has it overlapping with the section. How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{some text \arabic{section}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

\section{Example}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result: overlapping text in table of contents]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This should help: [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415)

Answer (score 1):

The `titletoc` package offers an easy way to configure the entries to the ToC.

```
\titlecontents{⟨section⟩}[⟨left⟩]{⟨above-code⟩}
{⟨numbered-entry-format⟩}{⟨numberless-entry-format⟩}
{⟨filler-page-format⟩}[⟨below-code⟩]
```

It is possible to add text before the section number by setting the numbered entry format. This requires enclosing the text in the number in a `parbox` wide enough to include the chosen text and up to two-digit section numbers to keep the section titles aligned in the ToC.

To simplify this process we used the `eqparbox` package which makes the boxes as wide as the widest member of the group (called `sect` in the example).

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eqparbox} % make  boxes as wide as the widest member of the group <<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{titletoc} % added <<<<<<<<


\titlecontents{section}
[0em]
{\vspace{.25\baselineskip}}
{\eqparbox{sect}{Some Text \thecontentslabel}\enspace}{}
{\hspace{1ex}\titlerule*[5pt]{$\cdot$}\contentspage}


\begin{document}
    
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

\section{Example}

\end{document}
```

To check the code add more text and/or create a section numbered with two digits.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eqparbox} % make  boxes as wide as the widest member of the group <<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{titletoc} % added <<<<<<<<


\titlecontents{section}
[0em]
{\vspace{.25\baselineskip}}
{\eqparbox{sect}{Some more Text \thecontentslabel}\enspace}{}
{\hspace{.5em}\titlerule*[10pt]{$\cdot$}\contentspage}


\begin{document}
    
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

\section{Example}

\setcounter{section}{9} % to create section 10

\section{Conclusion}
\end{document}
```

[image: d]

Sometimes it is necessary to compile twice when changing the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `tocloft` package for configuring ToC, LoF and LoT entries.

```
% tocsecnumprob.tex  SE 666590

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{5em} % more space for section number in ToC

\renewcommand{\thesection}{some text \arabic{section}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

\section{Example}

\end{document}
```