# Wrong TOC Formatting when using \numberwithin{section}{part}

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, formatting, numbering, section-titles

When I use the command `\numberwithin{section}{part}` the table of contents formatting gets destroyed.

A minimal working example is the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{section}{part}


\begin{document}


\tableofcontents{}

\newpage

\part{First PArt}
\section{First Section}
\section{Next Section}
\subsection{abc}
\subsection{ABC}

\part{Second PArt}
\section{The third Section}
\section{And another Section}
\subsection{This is an example}
\subsection{Example ;-)}

\part{Third Part}
\section{Wrong formatting}
\section{Another Section}
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{xyz}
\subsection{XYZ}



\end{document}
```

This yields the following table of contents: (I compile with Lualatex, if that is relevant)
[image]

As one can see the space between the numbering and the title of the sections is wrong and in case of Part 3 even overlaps.

How can I fix this?

Comment: This might help: [How to modify the space between the numbers and text of sectioning titles in the table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33841) (potential duplicate)  Also this: [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use (without `\numberwithin{section}{part}`)

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocdynnumwidth]{part}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[counterwithin=part,tocdynnumwidth]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[tocdynnumwidth,tocdynindent]
  {subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocdynnumwidth]{part}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[counterwithin=part,tocdynnumwidth]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[tocdynnumwidth,tocdynindent]
  {subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}
\clearpage

\part{First PArt}
\section{First Section}
\section{Next Section}
\subsection{abc}
\subsection{ABC}

\part{Second PArt}
\section{The third Section}
\section{And another Section}
\subsection{This is an example}
\subsection{Example ;-)}

\part{Third Part}
\section{Wrong formatting}
\section{Another Section}
\section{Test Section}
\subsection{xyz}
\subsection{XYZ}
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the `tocloft` package.

```
...

\usepackage{tocloft}
\addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{2em} % or other length
```

which will increase the space for the section number.