# Problem with table of contents, number of section overlap with their name

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering, section-titles

I have a problem with the table of contents, the section numbers overlap with their names, because I use a larger font for sections and subsections. Does anyone have an idea how I can improve this, or just move the numbers slightly to the left?
[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{exam}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    pdftitle={calosc}
    }
\usepackage{geometry}
\newgeometry{tmargin=2.6cm, bmargin=2.6cm, lmargin=2.5cm, rmargin=2.5cm}
\urlstyle{same}

\sectionfont{\LARGE}
\subsectionfont{\Large}
\subsubsectionfont{\large}
\paragraphfont{\large}

\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\LARGE\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecfont{\Large}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecfont{\large}

\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\LARGE\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecpagefont{\Large}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecpagefont{\large}
\setcounter{section}{9}
\begin{document}

\doublespacing
\tableofcontents
\singlespacing \newpage

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1}
\subsubsection{subsubsection 1.1.1}
\subsubsection{subsubsection 1.1.2}
\subsection{Subsection 1.2}
\subsection{Subsection 1.3}
\subsubsection{subsubsection 1.3.1}
\subsubsection{subsubsection 1.3.2}
\subsubsection{subsubsection 1.3.3}
\section{Section 2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE not compile.

Comment: Ok, I added more packs that I use, I must have forgotten one

Comment: See [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415).  Same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding three command of into your code, it works correctly.

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{12pt}
\addtolength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{12pt}
```

---

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{exam}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    pdftitle={calosc}
    }
\usepackage{geometry}
\newgeometry{tmargin=2.6cm, bmargin=2.6cm, lmargin=2.5cm, rmargin=2.5cm}
\urlstyle{same}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{12pt}
\addtolength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{12pt}


\sectionfont{\LARGE}
\subsectionfont{\Large}
\subsubsectionfont{\large}
\paragraphfont{\large}

\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\LARGE\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecfont{\Large}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecfont{\large}

\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\LARGE\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecpagefont{\Large}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecpagefont{\large}
\setcounter{section}{9}
\begin{document}

\doublespacing
\tableofcontents
\singlespacing \newpage

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1}
\subsubsection{subsubsection 1.1.1}
\subsubsection{subsubsection 1.1.2}
\subsection{Subsection 1.2}
\subsection{Subsection 1.3}
\subsubsection{subsubsection 1.3.1}
\subsubsection{subsubsection 1.3.2}
\subsubsection{subsubsection 1.3.3}
\section{Section 2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thats perfect, thank you very much :D

Comment: @MichałSzymankiewicz You're welcome :-).