# List of Figures customization

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, tocloft

I want to customize the list of figures. Here is my settings:

```
% Figures and table in the directories
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Table }
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure }
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{:}
\settowidth{\cfttabnumwidth}{Table 10 \quad}
\settowidth{\cftfignumwidth}{Image 10 \quad}
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}  % remove indentation from figures in lof
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0pt}  % remove indentation from tables in lot
\renewcommand\cftsecdotsep{\cftdotsep}
```

After certain figures the formatting becomes messy as shown:
[image]

latex code for loading image:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside, numbers=noenddot, bibliography=numbered, numbered=liststotoc, toc=listofnumbered, captions=nooneline, fleqn, dvipsnames]{scrartcl}


% Adalam _tp_fp_suggested
\begin{figure}[h]
     \centering
     \includesvg[width=\textwidth]{images/feature/dnn/affnet/_affnet_AdaLAM_tp_fp_suggested.svg}
     \caption{False Positives for DNN-based feature descriptors using AdaLAM Matcher}
\label{fig: adalam_tp_fp_suggested_dnn}
\end{figure}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome! Please make your code compilable. From `\documentclass`  to `\end{document}` with your full preamble. Meanwhile try `\settowidth{\cftfignumwidth}{Figure XIX.99\quad}`

Comment: Perfect. That worked

Comment: Related: [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415/5764)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `\settowidth{\cftfignumwidth}{Figure XIX.99\quad}` worked.