# KOMA table of content: space between section number and section title

Tags: koma-script

I produce a table of content with `\tableofcontents` and do not see how to add a bit of separating space between the section number and the title - they are run together. What should I change?

I read the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7415/roman-numerals-become-too-wide-in-table-of-contents) which refers in the title to `Roman Numerals` which is not my case; the answer nevertheless partially applicable, but most of the advice is for an obsolete package (`tocstyle`) and it is therefore somewhat tricky to identify the parts still valid. The current KOMA version has much simpler solutions, which I think should be searchable in StackExchange.

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[
headings=standardclasses,     % to use serif font for titles 
a4paper,    
10pt,
notitlepage
]{scrartcl}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}  

\makeindex

\addtokomafont{part}{\LARGE} % reduce size of part
\addtokomafont{partnumber}{\LARGE}

\counterwithin{section}{part}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}


\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents    
    \section{should be 0.1}
    
    Each page shows :
    
    \section{should be 0.2}
    
    The index pages list automatically.
    
    \part{is Part 1}
    
    \section{should be 1.1}
    Some nonsense text
    
    \subsubsection{should be 1.1.1}
    The tufte style does discourage
    
    \part{is Part 2}
    
    \section{should be 2.1}
    
    References 
    
\end{document}
```

and the output shows no space between section numbers and titles::

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the `dynnumwidth` option of the `tocbasic` KOMA configuration options (see KOMA manual). It essentially determines such run-ins in previous runs and adds space in the next run. In my experience, it usually works.

Comment: `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[dynnumwidth]{tocline}{section}` should work. Also move the `\counterwithin{section}{part}` behind the bookmark package so that hyperref updates also the target names for the links.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7415/roman-numerals-become-too-wide-in-table-of-contents) See, i.e., [esdd's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314015/277964)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: with your advice and some more search I found that adding `toc=flat` in the options for the documentclass sufficient and even simpler. Anything wrong with this?

Comment: well it gives another look. Take the one you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I found is to include `toc=flat` in the documentclass options like:

```
\documentclass[
      headings=standardclasses,     % to use serif font for titles 
      a4paper,
      10pt,
      toc=flat,  
      notitlepage 
  ]{scrartcl}
```

As Ulrike Fischer pointed out, it changes some other aspect of the ToC and her solution may be preferable in some cases.

Comment: As already told in a comment to the question. See [esdd's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314015/277964) to [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7415). This answer shows recommended KOMA-Script features. So I still think, that your question is a duplicate.