# To customize font size of subsections in table of contents?

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, formatting, fontsize, installing-fonts

I am trying to find a solution to use lower font size for subsections than sections.
In fact, my latex code is no more. I have things as follows:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{SelfArx} 
\begin{document}
\maketitle % Output the title and abstract box
\tableofcontents % Output the contents section
\thispagestyle{empty} % Removes page numbering from the first page
```

There are not any extra codes while writing sections and subsections. 
An example is as follows:

```
\section{The Existing Methods of Fuzzy Cluster Analysis for Categorical Data}
```

and

```
\subsection{Fuzzy k-means algorithm}
```

I could not find a solution to customize the font size of subsections in table of contents. I think that the problem may be related to the document class `\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{SelfArx}`. I cannot use any other packages instead of `SelfArx` because I use it as my article template. My current output for table of contents is as the following image. I do not know how I can touch the font size of subsections.

[image: Table of Contents]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  It looks like the fonts are the same size, but the section titles in bold make them look bigger.  The definition of the fonts used in the TOC is indeed in the document class file.  I think that the section line in the TOC is  defined as `\l@section` (didn't check).  The overlap of section number and text is dealt with in this earlier question: [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415)

Comment: Thank you, @barbarabeeton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the `tocloft` package.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{SelfArx} 
\usepackage{tocloft} 

\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\small}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\small}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpagefont}{\footnotesize}

\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\tableofcontents 
\thispagestyle{empty} 

\section{The Existing Methods of Fuzzy Cluster Analysis for Categorical Data}
\subsection{Fuzzy k-means algorithm}
```

Comment: But almost certainly shouldn't if this is a submission class ;).

Comment: That is the exact solution of my need& my problem. I am able to touch font sizes of the table of contents, now. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @MuratYazıcı As far as I can see, the class uses `titletoc` and it conflicts with `tocloft`. Your submission will likely be rejected.